# React javascript get value by ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, unique-values

I've got a question, how to get a value to find it by id?

Eg I got something like: "`{section,249013: 'some value', section,244242: 'another value'}`" and I need to put it into the object

```
const someObject = [
section: {
 id: 249013,
 options: [someArray],
values: I need to insert value here
},
section: {
 id: 244242,
 options: [someArray],
values: I need to insert another value here
}
```

]

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Let arrayofobjects = Object.keys(yourObjectThatContainsObjects) and declare a varibale lets say targetObject and do as follow:1-arrayOfObjects.forEach(key=>{if(yourObjectThatContainsObjects[key][id]===wantedId){targetObject = yourObjectThatContainsObjects[key]}). Something like that as i understood

Comment: I got to convert into id: value the object I got and then somehow place it into the object below.

Comment: it's quite unclear can you clarify a bit more?i suppose that you want to conditionally add a new object according to the id you want to search for, into the bigObject which's containing all other objects right?

Comment: I get from backend object which in properties has sectiond,id: values. I have to seperate them and put them into right place into my object which I showed below. I have to put those values into the properties values in the object of someObject.